# Ubuntu 14.04 - restart success, shutdown hangs

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday on a 160 GB Hdd. It currently has only one OS and disk is fully encrypted. The problem occurs when I press `shutdown` and system hangs on screen with text **Ubuntu**. I have enabled the `splash` and got these lines :

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
 * Stopping rsync daemon rsync
 * speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Asking all remaining processes to terminate...
 * All processes ended within 1 seconds...
m-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
ModemManager [969]: <warn> Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
ModemManager [969]: <info> ModemManager is shut down

 * Deactivating swap...
 * Unmounting local filesystems...
 * sda5_crypt (busy)...
 * Stopping early crypto disks...
 * Stopping early crypto disks...
mount: / is busy
 * Will now halt
   471.291801] reboot: Power down
```

I have been experiencing the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04 on another Hdd, But is also had `Windows` installation and shutdown from windows was successful every time. So I was doing `restart` from `Ubuntu`, then `shutdown` from `Windows`.